# How to show only newly logged content in tail -f?

Tags: linux, unix, command, tail

Normally `tail -f` shows 10-15 already logged content. How can I avoid it? I only want to see newly logged content. Is there any switch in the tail command for that? Please advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply set to return zero lines:

```
tail -n 0 -f /var/log/syslog
```

man tail:

```
   -n, --lines=K
          output the last K lines, instead of the last 10; or use -n +K to output lines starting with the Kth
```